# Pindown cause of mysterious RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

Inherited this project so don't know a lot about the code. As of one week I've found out this error happens (RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded) Which leads me to believe there's been a change in the google v3 places api ?

The error can be observed here https://dev.salaun-limousines.com/pre-reservation 
The 2 inputs use google api to calculate the distance and determine the quote prices.

Selecting 2 random locations for example Angers as source and Etretat as destination yields no error.

This are the dispatched events I see in the console: [image] 
and these are the ajax requests made to google api:
[image]

However doing this with an airport as a destination (such as Nantes Atlantique Airport (NTE)) results in a RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded without fail as seen here

My current assumption is that the data returned from google places is somewhat not valid for that specific destination but have no idea how to test this. At first glance everything seems in order.

Anyone have any clue where to look? I can provide more code if needed for any of these actions. Most likely the error occurs in the SET_TRAVEL_DATA

Cheers.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure this is not an action loop in middlewares (saga or other) ?

Comment: Yes. This didn't happen last week and nothing changed in the code base to affect it. This error just popped out of nowhere.

Comment: Hmm it appears the error is gone for now .... This is the most bizarre thing I've ever seen in my life.